# $T$ fixes exactly $2$ points of unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra

could any one just give hints for the following?

$T\neq I$ is a orthogonal  operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $det T=1$, we need to show that $T$ fixes exactly $2$ points on $S^2$

well, I was just thinking by contradiction if it fixes $3$ points say $(x_1,x_2,x_3),(x_4,x_5,x_6),(x_7,x_8,x_9)\in S^2$ then calculated the matrix of $T$...am I going in right path?

Comment: Have you determined the possible eigenvalues of $T$? Observe that a fixed point must belong to the eigenspace $\lambda=1$. If there are more than two, then the dimension of the eigenspace must be ... See [my answer to another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/59166/11619) for a related argument (and other answers there for more discussion). Undoubtedly the same argument has been given many times in this site.

Comment: every rotation has axis so it must have $1$ as an eigen value, I dont know more.

Comment: Good. How many fixed points will one axis give you?

Comment: Correct. What can you say about the dimension of the eigenspace of $\lambda=1$, if there are at least three fixed points?

Comment: $2$ , as eigen vectors generates a plane.

Comment: What's the product of all three eigenvalues? If you know two of them, then what about the third?

Comment: product of all eigen values will be $1$, the third must be $1$

Comment: So at that point you have an orthogonal transformation $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\lambda=1$ as a multiplicity 3 eigenvalue. That leaves very few options for $T$. Or another way to make further progress: a 2-dimensional eigenspace will intersect the orthogonal complement of the axis of rotation (=the plane of rotation) in a non-trivial way. If a rotation (on that plane) fixes a non-zero point, then ...

Comment: $T$ must be identity transformation. i did not understand the 2nd way, I am poor in english

Comment: Correct. You might benefit from typing up the full argument as an answer. That way you get more feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You are going the right path. Since you only want a hint: Compute the matrix with respect to a specific basis. Then use that the matrix is special orthogonal.

Comment: well, the matrix w.r.t standard basis is $\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_4&x_7\\x_2&x_5&x_8\\x_3&x_6&x_9\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: How did you conclude that? The $x$-vectors are mapped to themselves, but how do you know where the standard basis vectors are mapped?

Comment: so what basis i must chose?

Comment: One consisting of the vectors you have, namely the $x$-vectors (how many of them are/can be linearly independent?).

Comment: I am not understanding :(

Comment: Do you know what the columns of a linear operator with respect to a chosen basis are?

Comment: +1 But it is not clear to see a natural choice of basis. What did you have in mind: two linearly independent fixed points and their cross product?